# What is the purpose of data-indexable and data-name attributes on a hyperlink?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I ran into this URL on a website:

```
<a href="#" title="Blue" data-indexable="1" data-name="color-blue" class="linkfilter color">Blue</a>
```

What purpose do the properties data-indexable and data-name serve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standardized meaning behind specific `data-*` attributes; rather you create them for your *personal* needs. In this case, the name suggest that one will help index this element among others, or help identify its current location among others. The other, may exist to give additional information about the element and its value - there's really no telling.

As the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) says:

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own valid attributes on html elements as long as your prefix them with data-. It is useful when building ajax/rich internet applications.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` attributes in HTML are custom attributes. They have no meaning in terms of HTML specifications. They simply allow an author to store data to be used in scripts, for example.